# Simple Client-Server application using sockets

Tags: android, scala, sockets, client-server

I work on a "Hello world" **client/server** application and I'm struggling with the connection between the **server** ,which is written in **scala** and runs on my PC and the **client** ,which is written in **android** and runs on my phone.

I connected both applications on the same subnet ,i.e. my router and set the corresponding ip and port for them.
  The problem is that the client ,which is written in Android stops instantaneously.

P.S. I didn't post my IP address for security reasons.

The Server code is:

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
import scala.io._

object MyServer extends App
{
    try
    {
       val server = new ServerSocket(4242)
       println("Serve initialized:")
       val client = server.accept

       val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
       val out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream())
       var message =in.readLine()
       while(message != null)
        {
         println("Server received:" + message)
         out.println("Message received")
         out.flush
         if (message.equals("Disconnect")) 
          {
            client.close; 
            server.close;
            println("Server closing:")
          }
          message= in.readLine()
         }
    }

    catch 
    {
       case e: Exception => println(e.getStackTrace); System.exit(1)
    }
}
```

The client code is:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ghiurutan.clientv1.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="158dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/text_view_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ghiurutan.clientv1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ghiurutan.clientv1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVER_PORT=4242;
    private static final String SERVER_IP="";
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private String messageToSend;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try{
                            socket=new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP),SERVER_PORT);
                        }catch(UnknownHostException e)
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }catch(IOException e)
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        try{
            printWriter=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
        }catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(
              new Button.OnClickListener()
              {
                  public void onClick(View v)
                  {
                      messageToSend=editText.getText().toString();
                      editText.setText("");
                      printWriter.println(messageToSend);
                  }
              }
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I must mention that I'm just a beginner in programming ,so any help or suggestion is welcomed.
    Should I use port forwarding in such a case? Someone told me that it is a good idea to put the server on the cloud ,because then it will be more visible.

Comment: `and set the corresponding ip and port for them`. Unclear. What did you do?

Comment: The first problem i see is that you do not all network code in a thread. Yes you open the socket in the thread. Ok. But not the print writer and the println(). All network code should be executed in a thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: So you will have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` clearly visible in the logcat. And which makes your app crash. You did not report that.

Comment: In your manifest you forgot to request the INTERNET permission.

Comment: `I didn't post my IP address for security reasons.`. You can safely post internal LAN addresses like 192.168.1.12 as we have all the same. Millions have that.

Comment: `stops instantaneously.`. Ok. You reported. It crashes. It crashes as it has not even INTERNET permission.

Answer (score 2):

The final code, that actually works, is the following:

```
package com.example.ghiurutan.clientv1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVER_PORT=8888;
    private static final String SERVER_IP="192.168.100.2";
    private EditText currentEditText,destinationEditText;
    private TextView resultTextView;
    private Button button;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private String currentLocationMessage,
    destinationLocationMessage,messageReceived;

//Called when the activity is first created
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        currentEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        destinationEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        resultTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);


        button.setOnClickListener(
                    new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        currentLocationMessage = currentEditText.getText().toString();
                        destinationLocationMessage=destinationEditText.getText().toString();
                        currentEditText.setText("");
                        destinationEditText.setText("");
                        new Thread(new SendMessage()).start();
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    private class SendMessage implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String inputMessage=currentLocationMessage+"#"+destinationLocationMessage;
                socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP), SERVER_PORT);
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                printWriter.println(inputMessage);
                printWriter.flush();
                currentLocationMessage="";
                destinationLocationMessage="";
                messageReceived = bufferedReader.readLine();

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                   @Override
                   public void run()
                   {
                       if(messageReceived==null || messageReceived.equals(""))
                       {
                           resultTextView.setText("Error.Please check the inputs.");
                       }else {
                           resultTextView.setText(messageReceived);
                       }
                   }
               });
                printWriter.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                socket.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

    }


//Called when the activity is about to become visible
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    //Called when the activity has become visible
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    //Called when another activity is taking focus
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }

    //Called before the activity is destroyed
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```